# File is empty when I open it with Process.Start(*vscode.exe-path*, *file path*)

Tags: python, c#, forms, visual-studio, process.start

I want to allow user to load a python project in VSCode from my application. The user is given a list of projects from which he chooses one and on click should open in VSCode. Projects folders and files are located at `C:\Users\Korisnik\Documents\Pygame Engine`.

I'm trying to open .py file with c# code located at `C:\Users\Korisnik\Documents\Pygame Engine\Test` with
`Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Korisnik\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\code.exe", projectPath + "\\" + projectName + ".py");`.

The `projectPath` variable is a path to the project (`C:\Users\Korisnik\Documents\Pygame Engine\Test`) and the projectName is "Test" in this case. The test folder contains the Test.py file.

I have some code previously written in that .py file, but when VSCode opens, the file name appears like a tab, but there is no code. When I save it, it saves at `C:\Users\Korisnik\source\repos\Pygame Engine\Pygame Engine\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Engine\Test` .

On the other hand when i try to open it with notepad with `Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe", projectPath + "\\" + projectName + ".py");`, the code is loaded and it saves in the `C:\Users\Korisnik\Documents\Pygame Engine\Test`, where it should be.

I just need that file to open in VSCode and the user to be able to modify and save it

Here is what I see when VSCode opens: [image]

Comment: Even after reading it a third time I don't get it. Can you please formulate and format your question more comprehensively? What do you want to achieve? What are the errors? What are the values of `projectPath` and `projectName`? Please also spend some linebreaks - it is very hard to read.

Comment: @mu88 I updated the question, if you are interested in anything else, feel free to ask me. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reformatting - much better  I tried to reproduce your described behavior, but I failed - it works on my machine. Could you please share some actual code from your application so that I can test it?

Comment: @mu88 I fixed it. The problem was that I didn't put a bottom line in the folder name between "Pygame" and "engine".

Comment: Perfect! I'm happy that you could solve the problem